# Phonegap FileReader not prompt alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I wrote a code I think it should work, but it doesn't :(

```
//FILE READER
function fileReaderHelper(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function(file){
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    alert("read success");
                    alert(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, failFile);   
        }, failFile);
    }, failFile);
}
```

Can anyone see the mistake, or know why not wokrs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

I forgot this line:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```